# SQL Error ORA-00979 'not a group by expression' but I can't figure out whats wrong with my group-by statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to get all of the 'sp_saleprice' records from my sales_purchases table only where the sales_person responsible for those records has nothing present in 'sp_sup' (i.e. they're a supervisor). 
However, I keep getting the following error when I run the code...

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I don't understand why, because I have a GROUP BY statement.

Here's the entity-relationship model 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0J4Vk.png

```
SELECT p.sp_id, p.sp_fname, p.sp_lname, sp.sp_invoice,
'$' || to_char (MAX (sp_saleprice), 'FM999999999.99') "Max",
'$' || to_char (MIN (sp_saleprice), 'FM999999999.99') "Min",
'$' || to_char (SUM (sp_saleprice), 'FM999999999.99') "Total",
'$' || to_char (MEDIAN (sp_saleprice), 'FM999999999.99') "Median",
COUNT(sp_saleprice) AS AMOUNT
FROM sales_purchases sp, sales_persons p
WHERE sp.sp_id = p.sp_id
    AND sp_sup IN (
        SELECT sp_sup
        FROM sales_persons p
        WHERE sp_sup IS NULL)
GROUP BY p.sp_id, p.sp_fname, p.sp_lname, p.sp_sup;
```

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: jarlh - thanks for that!

Comment: Hint:  `sp.sp_invoice`.

Comment: Hint: don't use the older implicit join with comma-listed tables in `FROM` but use explicit `JOIN`, introduced as standard in SQL over 25 years ago.

Comment: I have resolved the group-by error, but I am not getting the expected results.
Here are the entries for sales_persons: https://i.imgur.com/dRGYv5W.png
Here are the entries for sales_purchases: https://i.imgur.com/f36zYsE.png

I was expecting to get all of the sales records for sales_purchases where the sales person in sales_persons does not have an allocated 'sp_sup' (supervisor) which would mean that they are supervisors themselves.
When I run the query I just get "no rows selected" as a response, when I should have ten results

Comment: Please do not post links to images of data in comments. If you want to add data then [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56561914/edit) to include it as text (preferably DDL/DML statements).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query selects without aggregating the columns:

```
p.sp_id, p.sp_fname, p.sp_lname, sp.sp_invoice
```

but your `GROUP BY` is on the columns

```
p.sp_id, p.sp_fname, p.sp_lname, p.sp_sup
```

The last one is different in those lists.

> I was expecting to get all of the sales records for sales_purchases where the sales person in sales_persons does not have an allocated 'sp_sup' (supervisor) which would mean that they are supervisors themselves. When I run the query I just get "no rows selected" as a response, when I should have ten results

```
AND sp_sup IN ( SELECT sp_sup FROM sales_persons p WHERE sp_sup IS NULL )
```

Is going to exclude all rows as the nested select is always going to return `NULL` values.

Why not just use:

```
SELECT p.sp_id,
       p.sp_fname,
       p.sp_lname,
       sp.sp_invoice,
       '$' || to_char (MAX (sp_saleprice), 'FM999999999.99') "Max",
       '$' || to_char (MIN (sp_saleprice), 'FM999999999.99') "Min",
       '$' || to_char (SUM (sp_saleprice), 'FM999999999.99') "Total",
       '$' || to_char (MEDIAN (sp_saleprice), 'FM999999999.99') "Median",
       COUNT(sp_saleprice) AS AMOUNT
FROM   sales_purchases sp
       INNER JOIN sales_persons p
       ON ( sp.sp_id = p.sp_id )
WHERE  sp_sup IS NULL
GROUP BY p.sp_id, p.sp_fname, p.sp_lname, sp.sp_invoice;
```

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/VZNKWfI.png
That worked perfectly. Thank you for clarifying that for me.